# PrivateKey storage in server security

Tags: solidity, javascript, security

I am using my privateKey from my wallet to perform certain actions in my contract.
So far so good, but a question arose on how to more securely store my privateKey of my account on the server.
At first I'm storing it in the project's .env, but I would like to know if there are safer ways and what are they? (If you have eexamples it's much better.)

Comment: What OS is on your server (*NIX, Windows Server, so on)?

Comment: @MadJackal Ubuntu Server